# plotting output from FindRoot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am an R user and am totally new to *Mathematica*. I am trying to find the roots of a system of two equations over a series of paramter values and plot the results. I can do the computation but would love to know how I can work with the results without exporting them from *Mathmatica*.

```
 alphas = Table[
          FindRoot[ {
          S1*(1 - Exp[-R01*(1 - alpha)*Zinf1/N1 - R02*alpha*Zinf2/N2]) - Zinf1,
          S2*(1 - Exp[-R02*(1 - alpha)*Zinf2/N2 - R01*alpha*Zinf1/N1]) - Zinf2} == 0, 
          {Zinf1, 10000},
          {Zinf2, 10000}], {alpha, 0, 1, .1}]
```

This seems to return a list of named lists (each element being something like `{Zinf1 -> 9403.65, Zinf2 -> 9800.66}`).  I would like to plot all the `Zinf1`'s vs. `alphas` and thought something like `ListPlot[]` could do it, but it seems to have issues with the name:

```
ListPlot::optx: Unknown option Zinf1 in ListPlot[Zinf1->9403.65,Zinf1->9475.33,Zinf1-    9533.97,Zinf1->....
```

Any idea how to get this data into an easier (perhaps unnamed) form?

Comment: Try the following: `ListPlot[{Zinf1, Zinf2} /. alphas]` This will allow for each replacement of the Zinf1's and Zinf2's one by one from the solutions.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to post that as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alpha1` has given you a `Table` of replacements. You just need to create something in which you can make these replacements. A command of the form `{a,b}/.{a->1,b->2}` will give you `{1,2}`. Similarly in this case you can pass the whole table in as follows:

```
ListPlot[{Zinf1, Zinf2} /. alphas]
```